# Cannot see variable value while debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

The codes are shown below, I set a break point in order to check whether file created successfully, but the variable values is an empty string in debugging window,as figure shows, why this happens? may be need open some options of IDE?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "img.png");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image]

The android studio version is 3.1.4

**Edited**:
The question now serious impacts my development, I will read the file like this:

```
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();//throw exception 
        }
```

But I could see the file is really existed in my app private folder, why this happed? I tried to write and read file in external storage, but the same result.

Comment: The file created successfully, which could be viewed via device explorer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird problem. As when I tried the code you posted in my test application, I can see the value for `getFilesDir()`. It points me in the direction that it can be an environment issue. In my case, I tried checking this on an emulator which has the configuration as Nexus 6p with API level 23. I would suggest trying using some other device or new emulator with different config which you already have. This can be an emulator or device bug.

Comment: upvote your answer, I also suspect its a device related problem, but my application must have to run on one or two specific devices, so this is very annoy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. "Enable `toString()` object view" was helpful in my case.

> Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Data Views > Java